# ECS logging to cloudwatch from SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a springboot application running on ECS (Fargate)

When the task starts and the app boots I see a log from the main method of the Applicaiton class. However, from a Controller, debug messages are not showing up

Example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
@SpringBootApplication
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("######## Booting app #######");<-- this gets logged, shows in cloudwatch
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


In a controller

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
@RestController
...
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

...
    logger.debug("######## test message #######");<-- this does NOT gets logged in cloudwatch
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it - added this to my application.properties, it still does not answer why it worked in a main method and not within a running controller...

```
logging.level.com.my.package=DEBUG
```